# How to skip to the next element when iterating over lines read from a file, in Python?

Tags: python, iteration

I'm trying to write a code that looks for a specific text in a file and gets the line after.

```
f = open('programa.txt','r') 
for line in f:
    if (line == "[Height of the board]\n"):
      ## skip to next line and saves its content

    print(line)
```

Comment: This question isn't as general as written. It's specifically about iterating over a file's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a flag so you know to grab the next line.

```
f = open('programa.txt','r') 
grab_next = False
for line in f:
    if grab_next:
        print(line)
    grab_next = line == "[Height of the board]\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

File objects are iterators in Python; while the `for` loop uses the iterator protocol implicitly, you can invoke it manually yourself when you need to skip ahead:

```
with open('programa.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == "[Height of the board]\n":
            # skip to next line and saves its content
            line = next(f)
        print(line)
```

Your example code is unclear on *where* to store the next line, so I've stored it back to `line`, making the original line header disappear. If the goal was to print only that line and break, you could use:

```
with open('programa.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == "[Height of the board]\n":
            # skip to next line and saves its content
            importantline = next(f)
            print(importantline)
            break
```

Comment: If file objects were not iterators, but only iterables, this wouldn't work; to do the same thing with a non-iterator iterable, you'd need to convert it to an named iterator explicitly with `seqiter = iter(myseq)`, iterate over the iterator created `for x in seqiter` and then you can use `next(seqiter)` within the loop to advance it manually (though you'll need a `try`/`except StopIteration` block to handle the case where manual iteration tries to go beyond the end of the list, or call `next(seqiter, None)` (or some other default besides `None`) for the case where the iterator is exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

Problems like this are almost always simpler when you *look back* rather than trying to *look ahead.* After all, finding out the last line is trivial; you just store it in a variable! In this case, you want to save the *current* line if the *previous* line was the header:

```
f = open('programa.txt', 'r')
last = ""
for line in f:
    if last == "[Height of the board]\n":
        height = int(line.strip())    # for example
        break                         # exit the loop once found (optional)
    last = line
```